WooCommerce Order Completed Webhook Issue
I found this custom order completed webhook topic. I added it as a code snippet and it was working fine for my purposes for a few days. Then it just seemed to stop working. This webhook is supposed to trigger a Make.com automation. When I check Make after an order comes in, it didn't even receive the webhook like it was. Why would it just stop working? Can you see anything in the code?
/*
Custom WC Webhook Manager
Add new webhook topic only for WC order completed.
Developed by Md Jahidul Islam ( oneTarek ) https://onetarek.com
*/ 

//Don't allow direct access
if( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;


if( ! class_exists( 'Custom_WC_Webhook_Manager' ) ) :
    
    class Custom_WC_Webhook_Manager {
        
        public function __construct() {  
            
            add_filter('woocommerce_webhook_topics', array( $this, 'add_custom_webhook_topics' ), 10, 1 );
            add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', array( $this, 'on_woocommerce_order_status_completed' ), 10, 2 );
            add_filter('woocommerce_webhook_payload', array( $this, 'add_custom_webhook_payload' ), 10, 4 );

        }

    
        /*
        Custom topics must start with 'action.woocommerce_' or 'action.wc_'
        described in the function wc_is_webhook_valid_topic
        If the topic name starts with 'action' then there must has a wp hook named with the string used after dot(.)
        So for this Topic we must have a wp hook 'wc_custom_order_completed'.
        Adding custom topic hooks using filter 'woocommerce_webhook_topic_hooks' does not work here.
        */

        public function add_custom_webhook_topics( $topics ){
            $topics['action.wc_custom_order_completed'] = 'Custom Order completed';
            return $topics;
        }

        //Trigger wc_custom_order_completed hook on woocommerce_order_status_completed hook.
        public function on_woocommerce_order_status_completed( $order_id, $order ){
            //We could use 'woocommerce_order_status_completed' hook name directly with the topic name.
            //But we are not using that direclty because , if in future WC pluign add new topic using that hook.
            do_action('wc_custom_order_completed', $order_id, $order );
        }

        /*
         * Set payload for our custom topic.
         */
        public function add_custom_webhook_payload( $payload, $resource, $resource_id, $webhook_id ) {
            
            if( isset( $payload['action'] ) && $payload['action'] == 'wc_custom_order_completed' && !empty( $payload['arg'] ) ) {
                $webhook = wc_get_webhook( $webhook_id );
            // Build the payload with the same user context as the user who created
            // the webhook -- this avoids permission errors as background processing
            // runs with no user context.
            //See build_payload() in woocommerce/includes/class-wc-webhook.php
            $current_user = get_current_user_id();
            wp_set_current_user( $webhook->get_user_id() );

                $version = str_replace( 'wp_api_', '', $webhook->get_api_version() );
                $resource = 'order';
            $payload = wc()->api->get_endpoint_data( "/wc/{$version}/{$resource}s/{$resource_id}" );
            
            // Restore the current user.
            wp_set_current_user( $current_user );
                
            }
            return $payload;
        }
    
    }//end class
    
endif;

$Custom_WC_Webhook_Manager = new Custom_WC_Webhook_Manager();

Thank you!
See the above for the explanation
